# Two WordPress blogs on the same domain - How to add the sitemap?

Tags: seo, google, sitemap

I have two WordPress blogs on the same domain.

**example.com** - One WordPress installation, and,

**example.com/tutorials** - another WordPress installation

*example.com* has very less content (as well as low quality).

*example.com/tutorials* has quality content. (I especially target all the SEO traffic to the posts on this directory)

Do I need to add a sitemap to both the blogs? What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the Yoast SEO plugin on both installations and then add the generated sitemaps to your Google Webmasters account. Google Webmasters allows you to submit multiple sitemaps, so it should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thanks. Is there way to mention that important sitemap is 2nd one? What I mean is, specially I target SEO traffic for "example.com/tutorials"

Comment: I don't think so. Although, it shouldn't really matter, to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

When installing YOAST on both Wordpress installations, I'd also suggest you create one sitemap index file which should be available at root level of the domain (that is: example.com/sitemap-index.xml), AND referring to the sitemap index file in your robots.txt. You can edit robots.txt manually in Wordpress once you use YOAST. The sitemap index file should refer to both sitemaps. As an alternative, you can set up one robots.txt on root level of the domain that works for both the root and the subfolder, and reference the two sitemap locations in the robots.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a major problem here, that I recently discovered; Maybe it's a bug with my structure but when I add a sitemap in the example.com/tutorials's Search Console, it automatically shows in the example.com/'s Search Console (although these are separate properties, with separate Tag manager containers, etc., BUT created in the same company Google account).

[image: Showing image from Wordpress1 installation]